# capture response data into an array using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Capture response data into an array using python:

When I read an url using urlib2 I get the below response in the console using print resp

```
code : resp = urllib2.urlopen(memberProfileInfo).read()

Console display 
OCODE: 11
UCODE: XXX
GID: XXXXXX
GDISP: XXXXX
\# rc=0, count=1, message=Success
```

How do I capture these values of ocode etc into arrays using python 2.7 ?

Comment: What have you tried? I would say, use a package for excel writing/reading such as xlsxwriter, xlutils or openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

```
I did this and it worked:
Code as below:
profdata = []
resp = urllib2.urlopen(memberProfileInfo).read()
profdata = resp.split('\n')
return profdata

However now in the excel I get all the response appended:
OCODE: 11 UCODE: XXX GID: XXXXXX GDISP: XXXXX \# rc=0, count=1, message=Success

Can we use regex and only capture data after : ? any suggestions here for the rest of the capture.
```